# Get fully-qualified class name from jclass (JNI) for use in FindClass

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Let's assume we hav an instance of jclass:

```
auto objectClass = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
EXCEPTION_RETURN(env);
```

On the next line, I want to get the name of the class and store that so I can use `FindClass` later on.

I've tried using `getName()` method but that returns a java class name and we can't use that in the `FindClass`. Here is my code for the `getName()` approach:

```
std::string GetObjectClassName(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaObject)
{
    auto javaClass = env->GetObjectClass(javaObject);
    EXCEPTION_RETURN(env);

    auto javaClassClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Class");
    EXCEPTION_RETURN(env);

    auto javaClassNameMethod = env->GetMethodID(javaClassClass, "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    EXCEPTION_RETURN(env);

    auto javaClassNameJString = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(javaClass, javaClassNameMethod);
    EXCEPTION_RETURN(env);

    auto javaClassNameC = env->GetStringUTFChars(javaClassNameJString, 0);
    EXCEPTION_RETURN(env);
    std::string javaClassName(javaClassNameC);

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(javaClassNameJString, javaClassNameC);
    EXCEPTION_RETURN(env);

    return javaClassName;
}
```

Notice that the returned class name can't be used in the `FindClass()` method. Is there a simple way for us to get the class name from `jclass` object?

Comment: _"Notice that the returned class name can't be used in the `FindClass()` method."_ Seems to me like the only problem with the returned string is that it contains `.` as a delimiter instead of `/`, which would be easy to fix.

Comment: @Michael Sometimes it seems that the "fully-qualified" names have extra special characters like $ and ^ so I am not sure we can do a simple "replace . with /"

Comment: `$` shouldn't be replaced, only the periods. E.g. `a.b.c.Foo$Bar` should become `a/b/c/Foo$Bar`.

Comment: Excuse me? What is this question about? `FindClass` returns a `jclass.` ***You already have the `jclass.`*** You don't need any of this.